# Injective curve

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

How can i show that the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\gamma(t)=\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2},\frac{t}{1+t^4}\right)
\end{equation}
is injective (without using algebraic geometry techniques)? Does a general way to show it exist for general curves?

Comment: What do algebraic geometry techniques refer to? (Example)

Comment: $\gamma(s)=\gamma(t)$ if and only if the two polynomials 
\begin{align*}
p(x,y)&=x(1+y^2)-y(1+x^2),\\q(x,y)&=x(1+y^4)-y(1+x^4)
\end{align*} are $0$ at the point $x=s, y=t$, so one can define the variety of $p$ and $q$ and study the part off the line $x=y$.

Comment: My solution is an extension of what you have sketched above. But I dont consider that it already belongs to the domain of algebraic geometry. It's "good ol' time" XIXth century methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f:t \mapsto \frac{t}{1+t^2} $$
is an "almost injective" function: $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $xy=1$. In such a case, however,
$$ g(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^4}\neq \frac{y}{1+y^4} = g(y)$$
unless $x=y=1$.

Comment: Sorry Jack, but i don't understand the proof. Why is necessary that $xy=1$?

Comment: @Mic.R: $f(t)=f(1/t)$ and $f(t)=K$ cannot have more than two real solutions, since $f(t)=K$ boils down to a second-degree equation.

Comment: Your solution is a very efficient one. The only point with which I disagree is the expression "almost injective": all points of $(-1/2,1/2)$ have two preimages...

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a standard method for such problems, relying on the definition of injectivity. Here it is: let us assume that

$$\gamma(s)=\gamma(t)$$

with the objective to deduce that necessarily $s=t$.

or, in an equivalent way, that there doesn't exist a couple $(s,t)$ such that

$$\gamma(s)=\gamma(t) \ \ \ \text{with} \ s \neq t \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Assume that such a couple exist: (1) is equivalent to $$x(s)-x(t)=0 \ \text{and} \ \ y(s)-y(t)=0$$

Easy computations where we cautiously preserve factors $(s-t)$ bring the equivalent conditions:

$$(s-t)(st-1)=0 \ \text{and} \ (s-t) (s^2t^2+st^3+s^3t-1)$$

But, by hypothesis $s \neq t$; therefore, the preceding double condition is equivalent to:

$$st=1 \ \text{and} \ s^2t^2+st^3+s^3t-1=0 \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Using relationship $st=1$ in the second equation of (2) gives $s^2+t^2=0$ which is not compatible with $st=1$. Therefore we have obtained a contradiction.

Remark: one can observe that the curve of $\gamma$ has the origin as a limit point when $t \rightarrow \infty$.

[image]

Comment: Nice, my solution is similar:
i have
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
x^4y-xy^4-(x-y)=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}
\\
\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
x^4y-xy^4-(x^2y-xy^2)=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}
\\
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x^3-y^3)-(x-y)=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}&\cup
\begin{cases}
xy=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}
\\
\end{align*}
at the right we have xy=0 and x=y, so we don't consider it, then
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
(x^3-y^3)-(x-y)=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}\\
\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Then
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
(x^3-y^3)-(x-y)=0\\
x^2y-xy^2-(x-y)=0
\end{cases}

\\ 
\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-1)=0\\ 
(x^3-y^3)-\frac{1}{3}(x-y)^3-(x-y)
\end{cases}
\\
\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
(x^2+xy+y^2-1)=0\\ 
(x^2+xy+y^2-1)-\frac{1}{3}(x-y)^2=0
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
&\begin{cases}
(x^2+xy+y^2-1)=0\\ 
(x-y)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
but we assume $x\neq y$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just wonder why you don't factorize $(x-y)$ much earlier in your computation.